# sql-interactive-mode get product name for the buffer

Tags: sql-interactive-mode

I have 2 connections to different servers through sql interactive mode:

```
(setq sql-connection-alist
  '((mysql_server
      (sql-product 'mysql)
      (sql-server "server1")
      (sql-user "user1")
      (sql-password "secret1")
      (sql-database "db1")
      (sql-port 3306))
     (ms_sql_server
       (sql-product 'ms)
       (sql-server "server2")
       (sql-user "user2")
       (sql-password "secret2")
       (sql-database "db2"))))
```

I have yasnippets for MySQL. I want to use similar snippets for SQL server, but it has different syntax. How can I get the type of the current server for the buffer I'm using, so I could switch between snippets?

Comment: Isn't there a way to abstract the differences? Many languages (python, perl, ruby) seem to have bindings to do standard SQL things, no matter what the underlying database is (with the possibility of some exceptions). That would avoid having two sets of snippets to maintain and remember.

Comment: @NickD This is what I'm trying to do: snippets are the abstraction for the concrete syntax.